# Matching cell from two values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

need help here :) I am not excel expert

I have a simple spread sheet with some data and I need to find the matching values from another sheet. Some help would be appreciated.

The data looks like this:

```
    d1    d2    d3    d4    d5
c1  1     5     4     4     3
c2  2     4     9     1     2
c3  4     4     7     8     4
c4  4     7     1     9     2
c5  4     4     7     6     8
```

So above c1, c2 etc. means Code's and d1, d2 etc. means Dates (future dates).
The numbers between I need to catch in a different spread sheet

example

```
Code: c2 - User provides the code
Date: d4 - User provides the date

Value: 1 - this value I need to get with formula
```

Should I attach example file if needed?

If possible to use performance wise formulas as might be quite few of them. Perhaps INDEX/MATCH? if I know how to use it :) but I think also INDEX/MATCH will slow it down a lot, I might be wrong also :)

thank you for your help in advance.

EDIT:
Added screenshot, might help also what is needed.
[image: Sample Data]

Comment: So your example is in the second sheet?

Comment: The sheet has a custom name but that's not the problem. I don't know which formula and how to use it to catch the number 1 when the user enters code c2 in one cell as value and then he enters d4 in another cell as a value. I need the result in third cell. Take any cell numbers as I can modify it later for my needs. I just explained what I need to achieve as simple as I could.

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like the search is in the same sheet, not a different one? Also your screenshot doesn't match your data. Which is correct?

Comment: The screenshot is just a sample I quickly created for this purpose

Comment: OK,
I've added the answer based on your original values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assumptions / prerequisites:**

- Sheet1 cells (A1:F6) is your data / headers from your example
- Sheet2 cell B3 is where the user types the code
- Sheet2 cell B4 is where they type the date
- Sheet2 cell B5 is where the value displays

this would be your formula in Sheet2 C5

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:F,MATCH(B3,Sheet1!$A:$A,0),MATCH(B4,Sheet1!1:1,0))
```

Comment: This is working fine, I've adapted the formula for my workbook needs and I will mark as an answer. Is there a faster solution? Index/Match is taking ages to calculate as I have more than 100 formulas of this version and the data itself it is pretty big as well. I have data for more than 100 codes, and 2 years in future :)

Comment: Possibly, there is always more than one way of doing something. I am not well versed on the efficiency of Excel formulas so not show if another method would be faster / slower etc....
All I would say is that this is how I would tackle the problem

Comment: @SEarle1986 - You can make this formula work little faster if instead of using entire rows and columns you can specify your actual data range. e.g. as per the data in the screen shot you can use formula as `=INDEX(C2:G6,MATCH(C11,B2:B6,0),MATCH(C12,C1:G1,0))`

Comment: @Mrig - Thank you for your explanation also, but as I said that's only small sample. The real data is between 450 rows, and so far used columns up to VS. EDIT: What I meant to make it faster, instead of using INDEX/MATCH maybe perhaps there is other functions available to achieve the same result

Comment: How much are you expecting the row count to increase by? You could go to just row 1000 for example